# Does the flag on Dante's jacket change?

Tags: dmc-devil-may-cry

There is a flag on Dante's jacket, I first noticed this during the cut scene at the end of the first level. The flag is a sown on patch kind of thing, and is on his upper left arm. This flag was a flag of the United Kingdom.

[image: Dante's jacket with the UK flag]

However, I find it strange he would have a British flag, but as I am in England I wondered if this was in fact something that changes based on your location (or possibly regional settings). If so then I think it is a really nice touch.

Can anybody confirm if this does change based on you location? or via any other settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the [pictures found over Google images](http://www.google.com/search?q=dmc:+devil+may+cry&tbm=isch&safe=off), it looks like the UK flag is just part of the character design of Dante.

- [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XmBi.jpg)
- [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edslF.jpg)
- [Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlhku.jpg)

There is also a side note about this flag on [the DmC Wikia](http://devilmaycry.wikia.com/wiki/Dante_%28DmC%29):

> The Union Jack patch on the arm of Dante's coat was Ninja Theory's small way of adding in a nod to themselves as their offices are based in the UK.

But I 100% agree with you: it would've been a great idea to geolocalize the flag ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think we can delve a little deeper than this. I know this issue has receded, but since I still keep my wallpaper as this Dante, the flag had eventually provoked some thought. I'm writing this from my own interpretative point of view, so level with me. The British flag holds so many symbols and allusions. If anyone reading this has looked into the names of the characters, particularly those of Dante and Vergil, a connection can be made between Dante Alighieri and Vergil Maro (the Roman epic poets). Both are famous for their literary contributions. Dante wrote the *Divine Comedy*(About Dante venturing into the underworld to rescue Beatrice), while Virgil wrote the *Aeneid* (Particularly in Book6, Aeneas is guided into the underworld to get advice from his father). Under these pretences, I can safely say that the names of Dante and Virgil pay tribute to the forefathers of the Epic genre in literature. Britain, as we all know, has a rich history in literature as well. So we have this connection, but what does it mean??

My theory is this: the game pays tribute to the world's legendary empires, being Roman and Britain, who have both nearly controlled the entire world at one point (think Ceasar's reign and colonialism). Considering the geographic, Romans (Europe) and Britain (America), we have the world represented in the game. It's no wonder then, that *Mundus'* name in latin means *The World*. I'll leave this open for other interpretations.

Maybe I put too much thought into this, but having a background in English Literature, I could not help but draw these connections, and make sense of them. If anyone should read this, what do you think?